# Composition of constant functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

Given is a set $M$ and two **constant** functions:

$$f: M\rightarrow M, g: M \rightarrow M$$

That means for example:

$$f(x)=a, \forall x \in M$$
$$g(x)=b, \forall x \in M$$

And if $a \neq b$ than we have

$$g(f(x))=g(a)=b\neq a=f(b)=f(g(x))$$

OK. But I found now that this is given even if $M$ has only one element? Is this not contradictory to my proof?

Comment: If $M$ has only one element, there are no _two distinct_ constant functions $M \to M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is a singleton, then $M$ contains only one element (call it $a$) and the only constant function is $f(x) = a$ (and $g(x) = a$ as well). Your conclusion fails because your argument invokes the assumption $a \ne b$, which is no longer true when $M$ is a singleton.